# Perl regexp replace?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm checking to see if I can replace an include like this:

```
#include <pathFoo/whatever.H>
```

with:

```
#include "whatever.H"
```

to do so I would use the -i switch, but to check I am doing it correctly I am simply using the -p switch without -i. I have the following command:

```
perl -p -e 's/<pathFoo\/\(.*\)>/"$1"' thefile
```

but this isn't quite working and i'm not exactly sure which part is off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to escape the parens, i.e.:

```
perl -p -e 's/<pathFoo\/(.*)>/"$1"/' thefile
```

should work for you.

Also note the ending `/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i~ -pe's!<pathFoo/(.*)>!"$1"!' file
```

The following is safer:

```
perl -i~ -pe's!#include\s+\K<pathFoo/(.*)>!"$1"!' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Since TIMTOWTDI, here's a double substitution. Or rather a substitution and a transliteration:

```
perl -pe 's|^#include\s+<\KpathFoo/|| && tr/<>/""/'
```

So, just remove the `pathFoo/` part first, and if that succeeds, then transliterate the `<>` characters to quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you there:

```
perl -pi -e 's{#include[ ]+<.+?/([^/]+)>}{#include "$1"}g' file
```